# jQuery hide div, remove background and change page width on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a div on click (well i'm trying to slide it to the left), but what it will have to do is also from the main page div swap the background and also i think, swap the width of another div. I've got it swapping the background and removing the things I don't want (although they slide down rather then to the left)

This video shows what happens (and then at the end i use firebug to show you what i want to happen) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tti_L_ofelg&feature=youtu.be (edit: video online now)

Here is my html for the sliding div:

The CSS:

```
.slidingDiv {

}

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
var defOpen = 1;

 jQuery(".slidingDiv").show();
        jQuery(".show_hide").show();

        jQuery('.show_hide').click(function(){

        if(defOpen == 1)
{
    jQuery(".show_hide").show();
    jQuery("#bgwrap").css("background","url(assets/stripeclear.png) fixed 0 0 repeat-y")
    jQuery("#primary_right").css("width","")
    jQuery(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    defOpen = 0

} else {
    jQuery(".show_hide").show();
    jQuery("#bgwrap").css("background","url(assets/stripe.png) fixed 0 0 repeat-y")

    jQuery(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    defOpen = 1
}
```

So it's bgwrap that has the image in it that i have to swap to a clear one (to stop it being there as it's a fixed image on the left)

and primary_right seems to be the one when I remove the width goes full screen (what i'm really trying to acheive)

It also needs to be able to toggle closed and open!

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: You should definitely clean up your Windows desktop ;-)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, nor is the video.

Comment: To clarify the question. He just wants the content to go full screen after "sliding" the left div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the width to "inherit". That's essentially what you're doing when you are selecting the delete style in Firebug.

`jQuery("#primary_right").css("width","inherit")`

Answer (score 3):

question is not clear..but as far as i understood...you want to hide a left side division by which the right side division occupies full screen and vice versa..is it?????

if yes defOpen variable will not help u..use JQuery toggle function...datz the best way to do it...

Comment: While that's not the problem he's having, this is also good advice. The "toggle" accepts two functions. One for toggle "on" and one for "off". It would clean up the code a lot.